# Increasing performance losses when creating many tf.data.Datasets and sampling from them

Tags: performance, tensorflow, tf.data.dataset

To implement an ERP (Experience Replay Buffer) in TensorFlow I'm trying the following: I have some function, which creates and caches a tf.data.Dataset:

```
def create_data():
  my_data_ndarray = create_some_iteration_data_function()
  iteration_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(my_data_ndarray)
  iteration_dataset = iteration_dataset.map(lambda x: my_preprocessing(x))
  iteration_dataset = iteration_dataset.cache().prefetch(16)
  #iterate through dataset, so contents are actually cached after full iteration
  for elem in iteration_dataset:
    continue
  return iteration_dataset
```

These datasets each represent some shard from the total ERB, which I would like to implement - the total ERP dataset is then constructed by sampling from many such datasets via inbuilt TF logic. Of course first I prefill the dataset:

```
data = []
for _ in range(100):
prefill_dataset = create_data()
data.append(prefill_dataset)
for training_step in range(1000)
  new_dataset = create_data()
  data.append(new_dataset)
  #keep a maximum size of the list!
  if len(data)>200:
    data.pop(0)
  total_dataset = tf.data.dataset.sample_from_dataset(data, stop_on_empty_dataset=False, rerandomize_each_iteration=True)
  total_dataset = total_dataset.shuffle(shuffle_size).batch(batch_size).prefetch(4)
  iterate_some_samples(total_dataset)
```

This leads me to the first confusing finding regarding performance: I time how long the create_data function takes. I find it iteratively takes longer (starting around~0.28s/iter, ending above 0.5s/iter) the time required for create_some_iteration_data_function() stays constant.

Then I also iterate over the resulting total_dataset:

```
def iterate_some_samples(total_dataset):
  for i, elem in enumerate(total_dataset):
    my_training_function(elem)
    #Notice step << number of mini batches in total_dataset at any point!
    if i >= step:
      break
```

Again here I time how long iterate_some_samples takes. While the time required for my_training_function stays constant, the time taken up by iterate_some_samples harshly increases (starting around 4s/iter, ending above 8s/iter!). Interestingly I find this only increases while the length of data increases, even though this should not have any influence, as iterate_some_samples never consumes >10% of the total dataset.

My **question** is (1) why does this happen, (2) how could it be addressed efficiently (assuming I want to stick to a large dataset, which combines multiple smaller datasets).

Notes:

- This can not be caused by CPU throttling, I checked for it
- One wild thought for me was TensorFlow getting less efficient with number of graphs, which have been created?
- Yes I could simply save the all the data in ndarrays, and construct the total dataset from a slice into the result of stacking them, potentially solving many of these problems. However I generally work a lot with datasets and would prefer having some general solution, working natively with datasets here.